# How do I copy vertex groups from one object to another?

Tags: objects, vertex-groups, linked-data

So, I decided that a previous project contained exactly what I needed to expedite a new project, so I appended the appropriate objects form the previous project to the new one. This was great, because I didn't have to define new materials, &c.

Regrettably, though, I found out that when it came to vertex groups, where it would have been as helpful to be able to copy vertex groups from one object to another as it was to copy materials, I couldn't figure out how to do so.

Am I looking for a feature which does not yet exist?

NOTE: I did not expect the vertex groups to have assignments in the target objects, but it would have been handy not to have had to retype 25 names.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Vertex groups are object data, so they will be copied by <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd>*> Object data*.
However, this will *link* all other object data as well.

For a onetime copy of only object data, you might want to try the bundled *Copy attributes* addon.

Once it's enabled, call it with <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> (warning, this conflicts with object copy/paste):

[image]

Comment: How to disable conflict with object copy/paste?

figured out, I had to press ctrl+c, not command+c