# Vertex groups missing when opening file

Tags: vertices, vertex-groups

When I open my blend file,all of the vertex groups appear to be missing.
However when I tried to open it with blender's "recent files" option everything was fine.
What to do?

Comment: I also got the message "file written by newer blender binary,expect loss of data" now.

Comment: What version of Blender did you save the file in?  What version of Blender did you open the file in?

Comment: @Nathan,I opened it with 2.93 and saved it in 3.0 i think. It seems like the blend1 file works properly,but i want it to work as a blend file too.

Comment: This is expected: ["Note that opening a file saved in 3.0 in an earlier version means the vertex groups will not be available."](https://developer.blender.org/rB3b6ee8cee7080af200e25e944fe30d310240e138).

Comment: Can someone please write a plugin to fix this bug? Why would they break such important design features?

Comment: I had to use the Copy attributes addon to copy the vertex data: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/16273/32655 for my case I also have to export the mesh from Blender 3.x as a .fbx to import to blender 2.x to preserver the vertex groups. Literally a extra 5 minutes of work now.